# Git remote server repository file storage

Tags: git, bitbucket

I will be working on a number of iPhone/iPad apps soon and am looking at using Git as my version control system. In past projects (but not iOS based) I have used SVN. My main decision for switching to Git is the de-centralised structure.

I will be using a remote server as a central Git repository (most likely Atlassian's bitbucket). I haven't set this up yet, but in the meantime I have been testing Git locally.

I've read through a number of beginner resources and now have a fairly good grasp of the basics but there is one thing I need to confirm I understand properly.

*In my example below I am using a local version of Git on my Mac.*

I have created a local git repository called **git_test**. In this repository I have two dummy files called **file1** and **file2**. I understand that this is my working directory which contains my actual files (and not blobs).

I also understand that the central repository on a remote server should be bare and not contain the actual files of the working directory.

Let's assume that I have two users (User A and User B) with identical local repositories.

**User A**

- Modifies **file1**
- Commits **file1**
- Executes a push to the remote repository

**User B**

- Modifies **file2**
- Commits **file2**
- Executes a push to the remote repository

Am I correct in saying that the new blobs are uploaded into the **.git/objects** directory in the remote repository?

Then, when User A and User B execute a pull command on their local systems the actual file and not the blob is updated with the contents of the new blob. Is this correct?

Sorry for the long-winded question. I just hope everything makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry too much about the blobs inside the bare repository. What is better to understand is that every repository is made up of commit objects that contain the exact file structure at the time of the commit to that repository.

In your example, user A locally generates a commitA, user B locally generates commitB, they were both based off master on the bare repositiory which would have pointed to a commit object (say) commitBase. Which means both of them have a parent of commitBase.

When A pushes, he pushes his commitA to the bare repository, which moves the master branch pointer up to commitA. All the information about file1 is inside the commit object commitA (along with information about the rest of the file structure).

Before B pushes, he must get the changes for commitA into his repo first because the remote master branch pointer no longer points to commitBase. He can't push until he's in sync with the remote on the commit objects and branch pointers. Thus when he gets the commitA object into his repo, he's going to get fileA as part of that, which will appear in his filesystem if he does a pull or rebase, but will only get the commit object into his repository (not the file into his working directory) if he does a fetch. Fetch just updates git internally with the new commit objects without changing your own master branch pointer. It's at the point of merge/rebasing that git is going to have to make some decisions about the files in the working directory, like if common files have easy merging, or if new files can be just put onto disk, or if there's too big a conflict and you'll have to manually resolve the conflicts in the files.

In your simple example, you have no clash, so you would either rebase and make your commitA become commitA2 and have a parent of commitB, or merge and keep your commitA object's parent as commitBase, but generate a new commitM object that is the result of merging B and A.

How git internally represents this in its .git/objects dir in any of the 3 repositories is kind of irrelevant at this point. It might be compressing and moving stuff around to maximise its database of all those objects as it likes, but it's not something i've ever worried about when trying to understand how the commit objects to files work.

Answer (score 0):

When you push to the remote repo it will deny it if your local repo is behind to remote repo

Not sure if that answers your question

This makes sure that you do not try to change a file that was already changed - it forces you to pull the newest changes beforehand

Also when you pull to your local repo yes the actual file changes - in the git repo I believe it creates a new diff file iirc but I could be mistaken, all I know is that it does not actually overwrite the files remotely

Comment: Thanks very much, that clarifies my confusion.

Comment: If @DanZimm has answered your question can you please consider marking the response as the correct answer?